# If my test case fails the afterEach block doesn;t executes

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, cypress, cypress-after-hook

```
import SignInPage from '../../pages/signInPage.cy'
import ValidateAccountPage from '../../pages/validateAccountPage.cy'
import DeleteAccount from '../../pages/deleteAccount.cy'


type NewAccountCredentials = {
  username: string,
  password: string,
  vcode: number,
  uid: string
};



const clientUrl = "http://54.39.177.218:8080";
const serverUrl = "http://54.39.177.218:3020/api/v2";

const signIn = new SignInPage()
const validateAccount = new ValidateAccountPage()
const deleteAccount = new DeleteAccount()

describe('Smoke test', () => {

  let credentials
  let value
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.viewport(390, 844);

    cy.fixture('addDebtDetails')
      .then((data) => value = data)
    // create a new non-validated account in the back-end
    cy.request(serverUrl + '/test-accounts/free')
      .then(response => {
        expect(response.body).to.have.property("username");
        credentials = response.body;
      })

    cy.visit(clientUrl, {
      onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
        win.sessionStorage.clear();
        win.localStorage.clear();
      }
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    /* CLEANUP AFTER EACH TEST */

     deleteAccount.DeleteAccountMethod(credentials.password)
    cy.wait(3000)
    // must always delete the created account even if any of the above testing fails
    cy.request("DELETE", `${serverUrl}/test-accounts/uid/${credentials.uid}`)
      .then(response => {
        expect(response.status).to.be.equal(200);
      })
  })

  it('verifying a new user is able to login followed by validation being performed', () => {

    // sign-in
    signIn.SignInMethod(credentials.username, credentials.password)

    // validate account
    validateAccount.validateAccountMethod(credentials.vcode.toString())

    cy.wait(3000)
    // verify that we are on the home page and see the correct greeting and workspace name
    cy.get("app-greeting h3").should('have.text', 'Hi QA Test! Primary');


  })

})
```

//Page Account Login And Validation

```
elements = {

        profileIcon: () => cy.get('.fa-user-circle'),
        myAccountBtn: () => cy.get('.items > :nth-child(1)'),
        deleteAccountBtn: () => cy.get('.delete > .body-heavy'),
        inputPass: () => cy.get('.mat-form-field-infix'),
        confirmPassBtn: () => cy.get('form.ng-dirty > .mat-focus-indicator'),
        deleteMyAccBtn: () => cy.get('.danger')
    }
    DeleteAccountMethod(pass) {


        this.elements.profileIcon().click()
        this.elements.myAccountBtn().click()
        this.elements.deleteAccountBtn().click()
        this.elements.inputPass().type(pass)
        this.elements.confirmPassBtn().click()
        this.elements.deleteMyAccBtn().click()

}
```

If a user logins and while performing certain action the test case fails, I still want some action to perform like I want the user account to get deleted if the test case passes or fails in both scenarios
I have kept my delete account method in afterEach hook but that only works when the test case has passed.

Can someone please tell me about how I should delete the account which is once logged in and when test execution fails in the middle eg: not getting a css selector, how should I be still able to delete the account

Answer (score 0):

I thought Cypress had fixed this issue, but in any case, you can use `Cypress.on('fail')` event handler.

The trick is to make the `afterEach()` callback function a seperate function and call it in both the `afterEach()` and `Cypress.on('fail')` commands.

```js
const cleanup = () => {
  /* CLEANUP AFTER EACH TEST */

  deleteAccount.DeleteAccountMethod(credentials.password)
  cy.wait(3000)
  // must always delete the created account even if any of the above testing fails
  cy.request("DELETE", `${serverUrl}/test-accounts/uid/${credentials.uid}`)
    .then(response => {
      expect(response.status).to.be.equal(200);
    })
})

afterEach(cleanup)

Cypress.on('fail', cleanup)
```

Comment: It does work in this way, but the actions are not getting performed after the test case fails, I have to pass force : true in params, for click this is working but for typing if pass force true it's throwing an error

Comment: It is showing me clicking the element after failing but the element is not responding

Comment: You haven't shown the click() so can't comment on it. It may be that some of the commands you want to run cannot do so in a `Cypress.on('fail')` callback. You could try to do the cleanup in the `beforeEach()` instead.

Comment: Just updated the code above with showing how clicking is performed, can you please check now. I tried keeping it in beforeEach as well same issue. The action commands like click and type and not responding even tho it shows that they have gone to that selector

Comment: I am producing an error in my test case to fail by changing the greeting message and keeping it as "Hi Q Test! Primary" instead of "Hi QA Test! Primary"

Comment: Ok, so not working also in `beforeEach()` means some other issue - will see if I can spot it.

Comment: There's nothing jumps out from the info - only other suggestion is to make some ***negative*** assertion at the end of `cleanup()`, for example making sure greeting has gone away - `cy.get("app-greeting h3").should('not.have.text', 'Hi QA Test! Primary')`.